# How to understand the annotation "also"

Tags: dictionaries

I'm sometimes confused by notations from the dictionary. Simply put, I don't understand what it is trying to convey. Here is one example.

> 2.4 (**also** times) A portion of time in history or characterized by particular events or circumstances:

> Victorian **times**

> at the **time** of Galileo

> the park is beautiful at **this time** of year

source: [here](https://www.lexico.com/definition/time)

How should I understand the notation "also times"

Does it mean all the singular "time"s in the above sentences are interchangeable with "times" s and vice versa？To be specific, are these equally acceptable：

Victorian **time**

at the **times** of Galileo

the park is beautiful at **these times** of year

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It means that just that sense of the word *time* also may appear as the plural *times*.

It doesn't necessarily mean that the singular and plural are interchangeable, just that that sense occurs in both forms in particular expressions.
In your examples, *Victorian time* and *times of Galileo* sound wrong. *These times of year* sounds iffy too.

Comment: "These times of year" is fine if you're talking about multiple times, for example, "I love spring and summer, the park is beautiful at these times of year". I agree that the other two definitely sound wrong though.

Comment: @Jack, Fiona.  Thank you.   But the plurality of "Victoria times"  isn't because of being "multiple times" but convention.  It is still a single period of time.  Do I get it right?

Comment: _In Victorian times_  is a rather vague way of saying _during the reign of Queen Victoria_. It was a long one which saw many changes, but _times_ is also used in the sense 'characteristics of a particular period', as in The Times newspaper and the expression 'the life and times of [person]'.

Comment: @Robbyzhu  You're right, convention has a lot to do with it. *In the time of Queen Victoria* and *in Victorian times* both sound normal.